# Gitignore CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, github, gitignore

Before I put my very first (CodeIgniter) application on Github, I have a question about the [CodeIgniter .gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CodeIgniter.gitignore) file (see below). I do not have a development directory in my config directory. Can I just `.gitignore` `*/config/*` instead? What is the importance of the development directory in the config directory?

```
*/config/development
*/logs/log-*.php
*/logs/!index.html
*/cache/*
*/cache/!index.html
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many people set up development and production folders in their config folders. Codeigniter will load the correct file from the correct folder depending on the environment you set in the main index.php

If you're creating a public repository on github copy the files with passwords and keys (your config.php and database.php are the only two that come standard with the framework I believe) to a new folder called development inside config, then remove the passwords and paths and things from the ones in the root folder. Leave the gitignore as is.

This way when you push to git you aren't pushing your personal private information to the project.

Comment: Should I include the system and user_guide directories in .gitignore? (extremly noob CI user).

Comment: Generally it's good practice to not keep anything under version control that someone else is keeping under version control. The user guide definitely don't bother you don't need that on your live server anyway. System depends on whether you ever plan to update or not, if not version control it, if yes then I wouldn't. Does that help?

Comment: Yes it helps but I was thinking in version control the system directory as way to enforce an specific CI version for the project. This way if another developer clones the repository it gets the right CI version immediately an he doesn't need to download it. In case that I need to update CI I probably will have to do a major refactor anyway and replace the system directory entirely. Does this makes sense?

Comment: Yes that's a completely acceptable use case, as to updating no there would be no refactor as long as you stay out of the system files (you shouldn't ever be modifying them anyway) it would just be a matter of replacing the system folder and doing a git commit.